# Perturbation of tangent ball

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

As picture below, $A$ and $B$ are two balls, $\partial A\bigcap \partial B=\{k\}$, and $B$ contains $A$. How to show that 
$$
\forall h\in \partial B,\exists ~\varepsilon > 0  ~st~ A\subset B+\varepsilon\overrightarrow{hk}
$$

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall prove
$$A+\epsilon\,\vec{kh}\subset B$$
for a suitable $\epsilon>0$, which amounts to the same thing. Let $a< b$ be the radii of the two spheres. I claim that
$$\epsilon:={b-a\over b}$$
does the job.

*Proof.* Stretch $A$ with stretching center $k\in\partial B$ by the factor of ${b\over a}$. The resulting sphere $A'$ will then coincide with $B$. Now shrink $A'$ with shrinking center $h\in\partial B$ by the factor ${a\over b}$. The resulting sphere $A''$ has radius $a$, and touches $B$ at $h$ from the inside. It is easily checked that the center of $A''$ is given by $c+{b-a\over b}\vec{kh}$, where $c$ denotes the center of $A$.

Comment: Thanks.Seemly there is another way. Let $O_A,O_B$ are the center of circle. Then $O_A,O_B,k$ are in a line, angle of  $\overrightarrow{kh}$ and $\overrightarrow{O_A O_B}$ is acute angle. Then, if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, $|O_B-(O_A+\varepsilon\overrightarrow{kh})|<|\overrightarrow{O_AO_B}|$